# Windev CVS Repository

Tags: eclipse, repository, cvs, windev

Anyone knows if i can use a CVS Repository to versioning my Windev Project? and if i do, can i compile my versions through a CVS Respository?!

i have been working on these projects and they are build on Windev with Protegre, its sucks but i'm trying to make this experience better to me and my Developers.

Im trying to use a Eclipse IDE to manage the CVS respository, another trouble that i have is, when i try to import the Windev Project to a CVS repository i recieve the error There is no such repository.

Thx Anyway

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i don't think. But you could use GDS with Windev for versioning your projects. You could read more detail at this link http://doc.pcsoft.fr/en-US/browse.awp?cat=gds_gestionnaire_sources,39

I already use it and it works perfectly.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Well, sorry for all time that i made you wait, well, idk GDS well, indeed, i dont even know how it works, i was waiting for a GIT or SVN solution

Comment: Well, no problem. Btw, i asked to technical support if we could use another CVS than GDS. And we can't. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, well, CVS i already know, it's because the binary files, CVS donsn't work with these files, well, it's will be a real trouble to solve in the next months haha!

Answer (score 0):

It works very well with Subversion.

In my last company, I worked for more than 17 years with Windev (since 4.0) and we used Subversion to version source code.

We start using SVN with Windev 5.5 because the GDS didn't exist yet.
We upgrade Windev up to version 17 and still use SVN instead GDS.
It works perfectly.

Subversion can manage every type of file : binary, text, etc.
But obviously, you can't use functions like DIFF or Merge with binary...

To avoid conflict, we locked each file we wanted to work on (wdw, wde, wdc...) and the commit released the lock.

We used TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.net/about.html), a very nice tool.

Hope this help
Let me know if you want more explanations.

Comment: you went to explain a very different scenario from the one the user questioned. It's like someone asking if he can do diff's in SVN and I say, use Git because you can there. That would be a good comment maybe.

Comment: @bitoiu I don't agree with your comment. The question was 'is it possible to use CVS to version Windev project' and my answer is "Yes". But I have experience only with SVN (which is the successor of CVS...), so I mentioned it. The other answers said 'no it's not possible to use CVS, you must use GDS' but it's absolutely not true. You can use any version control with Windev (even Git)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use WinDev with binary sources with Github, SVN and GDS, but new in WinDev 25+, you can now save your project in plain text sources!

[WinDev 26, project description, text sources!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpQtT.png)

So you can make source code versioning now real! Even you can edit these .wdw and .wdg files with an editor, but scource code generators will fail, because PcSoft did some properties with encoding...

```
internal_properties : BQAAAAUAAAC8Sl0pfseidXE9/kBmawagKU2LQSv8bn6/vNDKIJF1LaO5OrXnJBCSprdxyfnkeSCSHo4FglHTPzGvuw==
```